# awk on unix AS/400 (Qshell)

Tags: ibm-unix-system-services

In linux, I can do this

```
echo "hello" > a.txt
awk 'sub("l", "x" )' a.txt
hexlo
```

But if I do it on Qshell, I get:

```
 echo "hello" > a.txt
 awk 'sub("l", "x" )' a.txt
 awk: 0602-562 Field $($
```

I have no idea of what's going on, cannot find much about awk on qshell online. Please help...

Comment: Are you sure that shouldn't be `awk '{ sub("l", "x" ) } ' a.txt`

Comment: I got 16,000 google hits with "0602-562". I looked at the first 10 cases, and in every one of them the code posted included a shell variable reference with $. So, are you sure you are running the code you think you are? Also, your code has an error: it should be within { }. As it stands, it is in the position of a pattern, and is evaluated as a boolean. Being as sub returns the number of substitutions, that will only print lines that contained "l". I doubt that is what you intended. AIX awk is not GNU/awk, but it is close enough to mawk and nawk that this cannot be a versioning issue.

Comment: @Paul it's usually POSIX. And `sub` is indeed POSIX - but I'm sure both expressions are missing the curly braces

Comment: @roaima As posted, it is equivalent to `sub ("l", "x") { print }` or `{ if (sub ("l", x") != 0) print }`. It won't throw this specific error code (or any error at all) in any awk these last 40 years, but it also does something rather obscure and therefore bad practice. Try his code with `echo hello; echo goodbye` and see the difference with and without the braces.

Comment: @roaima Actually, in braces it prints nothing. It just invisibly changes the current line sometimes.